# Replicating IRTPRO results in R (mirt or other package)

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate IRTPRO results in R. Using the `mirt` package, I'm able to set controls to be the same as what's in my IRTPRO control file, and it produces parameter estimates within two or three decimal places. This is the `mirt` code I'm running:

```
model <- "F=1-54
          PRIOR = (1-44,a1,norm,1.5,1.5), (1-44,d,norm,0,3), (1-44,g,norm,-1.6,0.5)
          MEAN=0
          COV=1"

mod <- mirt(scores,model,
            itemtype=c(rep("3PL",44),rep("gpcm",10)),
            quadpts=49,
            SE.type="SEM",
            technical=list(NCYCLES=25000))
```

Basically simultaneously running a 3PL on the first 44 items, and a generalized partial credit model on the following 10 items.

Is there any way of further improving correspondence between `mirt` and IRTPRO to four or five decimal places? Or is there another IRT package that can provide that level of correspondence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both software are converging to a relatively low criteria by default (EM terminates when all parameters change < .0001). They likely would match better if you decreased them to something closer to 1e-8, then you should see a 4-5 decimal point match between the two software packages.